# Axis in Excel graph showing wrong dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

*Disclaimer - I'm a novice with Excel.*

If you see the below screenshot, you will see that the dates along the horizontal access don't match the dates of the data column the axis is referencing.  If I change the "Number" "category" back to "general", the axis is labelled with the numbers 1-179 (the number of days in the report).

How do I fix this so it shows the actual day's date and not its number in the range?

[image]

If it helps, I've changed the horizontal axis back to general and taken the screenshot you can see below.

[image]

Comment: looks like you have not set the x-axis, when you do not set anything it defaults to the 1st Jan 1900. Can you show a screen of the graph set-up?

Comment: If your graph is a **line** graph, the x-axis will be sequential numbers. Change the graph to a **scatter** plot.

Comment: @Bandersnatch - this didn't help.
What did though is changing the data source of the horizontal access to be the entire E column instead of the E column heading (technically E1)

Comment: Good.  Glad you got it fixed.